# Mongodb map reduce limitation

Tags: mongodb

I have run a map reduce in MongoDB, but I got an error:

> Converting from JavaScript to BSON failed: Object size 18754411 exceeds limit of 16793600 bytes.

Comment: You are hitting MongoDB's document size limit: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: We can't tell a problem unless you actually show the code. That's how this site works. From the message you are either A. Doing something really wrong, because 16MB really is quite a lot B. You are trying to return the output "inline", and you will actually need to write to a collection instead. The latter would be the usual option. You really should have no need to use mapReduce over the aggregation framework in modern releases of MongoDB anyway. So ultimately you're still doing something wrong. But nothing to diagnose here. Edit your question with details.

Comment: I have write output in a collection.but still getting same error.

Comment: db.collection.mapReduce(mapFunction,reduceFunction,
{query: {}, out: "collection1", sort: {field:1}}
);